# Помогите исправить регулярное выражение

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

RegEx: `\" \"(.+)\"`

`!who -add STEAM_0:1:2281337 "Типа "да" "но нет"" "ага"`

Cсылка: https://regex101.com/r/u65TeD/1

надо чтобы выделяло слово `ага`

Comment: Если что, у меня есть уже регулярное выражение, ищущие 1 аргумент
https://regex101.com/r/BANPwx/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/u65TeD/3 может одним попробовать все делать, было бы удобнее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо запретить кавычки в совпадении и не забыть конец строки:

```
[^"]*(?="$)
```